# Istio Service Mesh and large http request uri

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy

I'm facing an issue that popped out due to a bad api design. There is a large (I mean huge: 11361 in length) request URI with lot of parameters that is being blocked (or maybe badly routed) by envoy proxy sidecar throwing a connection reset by peer. The request is done between a pod and a service inside the same K8s cluster.

By removing the envoy sidecar in the caller pod, the api call works normally even if the destination is deployed with the envoy sidecar.

This is the log showing up when I try to do a curl with that huge URI:

```sh
 "- - -" 0 UF,URX "-" "-" 0 0 1000 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "10.10.146.112:80" outbound|80||default-http-backend.default.svc.cluster.local
```

The destination shown in the log is a fallback internal service.

I've tryied to add an EnvoyFilter that increases the max header size, but I think that those rules are for incoming calls and not for outgoing requests.

The issue is showing up with both Istio versions 1.4.0 and 1.5.8

Any ideas to workaround this while the dev team does the refactor?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Could you add your virtual service and destination rules yamls? Could you show me an example of your request? Is that service, `default-http-backend.default.svc.cluster.local` healthy and running? Does it restart after the request or nothing happens with him? You can take a look at response flags [here](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/observability/access_log/usage). About the max header size, that´s correct, quoted from envoy documentation `The maximum request headers size for incoming connections`.